# HTML Agility Pack Find specific span

Tags: c#

I would like to find a span with a specific Id and retrieve the inner text. But I can't seem to find the way to do that.

can someone guide me with this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try something along the lines:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("foo.html");
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='foo']");
if (node != null)
{
    var innerText = node.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: `doc.GetElementbyId('foo')` is a bit simpler way than dealing with XPath.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to turn the whole thing into an XElement and query it that way when using Html Agility. Easier than xpath IMHO. But Darin's answer works

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack handled malformed HTML (in-the-wild) HTML. XDocument doesn't tolerate any malformed markup.

Comment: yes so you get the output fror HtmlAgility and turn it into an XElement.